# Can not build standart example "NetBeans Platform Quick Start Using Maven"

Tags: maven

I tried to perform muti-module example for integration maven and netbeans (https://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-maven-quickstart.html) step by step. When I finished coding I have known that it's necessary to add libs `org.openide.util` and `org.openide.util.lookup` in my maven app. So I can't find the way to do this.

I find some repos which contains this libs:

- `oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/com/googlecode/sarasvati/thirdparty/netbeans/org-openide-util/7.3/` and
- `repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/googlecode/sarasvati/thirdparty/netbeans/` )

But when I trying to add this repo in netbeans it refuse to index it.

Then I'm trying to add repo in pom.xml. In TextFilter module I'm add:

```xml
... <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
        <id>org_openide_util_repo</id>
        <url>https://repository.sonatype.org/service/local/repositories/atlassian/content/org/codeartisans/thirdparties/swing/org-openide-util/8.6.2/</url>
      </repository>
    </repositories>

...

<dependency>
        <groupId>org.codeartisans.thirdparties.swing</groupId>
        <artifactId>org-openide-util</artifactId>
        <version>8.6.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codeartisans.thirdparties.swing</groupId>
            <artifactId>org-openide-util-lookup</artifactId>
            <version>8.3.1</version>
    </dependency> ...
```

But when I trying "build with dependencies" MavenPlatformWordApp, I get mistake:

> Failed to execute goal
>   org.codehaus.mojo:nbm-maven-plugin:3.13:cluster-app
>   (default-cluster-app) on project MavenPlatformWordApp-app: Failed to
>   retrieve the nbm file from repository: Could not find artifact
>   org.codeartisans.thirdparties.swing:org-openide-util:nbm:8.6.2 in
>   netbeans (bits.netbeans.org/nexus/content/groups/netbeans/)

I'm tryed to add reference to repo in pom.xml MavenPlatformWordApp, them mistake takes the form:

> Failed to execute goal
>   org.codehaus.mojo:nbm-maven-plugin:3.13:cluster-app
>   (default-cluster-app) on project MavenPlatformWordApp-app: Failed to
>   retrieve the nbm file from repository: Could not find artifact
>   org.codeartisans.thirdparties.swing:org-openide-util:nbm:8.6.2 in
>   org_openide_util_repo
>   (repository.sonatype.org/service/local/repositories/atlassian/content/org/codeartisans/thirdparties/swing/org-openide-util/8.6.2/)

Google search is nothing to help me. I can't understand whats the problem, please try me.

And one more thing:

If follow example instructions, filds "`TextFilter filter`" and "`Lookup.getDefault()`" in TextTopComponent.java in MavenWordEngine module are not existing. I'm add import org.openide.util.Lookup on top of TextTopComponent.java and trying to add import com.mycompany.textfilter.TextFilter. But TextFilter is not visible in TextTopComponent.java despite the fact that I maked the TextFilter Interface public. Will you explain my mistakes?

Comment: The `url`-Element in your POM doesn't contain the correct URL to the sonatype repository. `/org/codeartisans/thirdparties/swing/org-openide-util/8.6.2` is too much

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `url`-Element in your POM with this:

`<url>https://repository.sonatype.org/service/local/repositories/atlassian/content</url>`

Then the dependencies to `org-openide-util` and `org-openide-util-lookup` can be resolved.

The URL that you are using points to a single artifact and not to the whole repository.

**Update**
Maven says that it is looking for org.codeartisans.thirdparties.swing:org-openide-util:**nbm**:8.6.2 I don't know why. The artifcat type nbm belongs to netbeans, and I'm not familiar with netbeans. Try this:

```xml
 <dependency>  
     <groupId>org.codeartisans.thirdparties.swing</groupId>  
     <artifactId>org-openide-util-lookup</artifactId>  
     <version>8.3.1</version>  
     <type>jar</type>  
 </dependency>
```

Comment: thanks, new url is really apply include this repo to netbeans, but when i add it in pom.xml I got previous mistake:

Comment: thanks, new url is really apply include this repo to netbeans, but when i add it in pom.xml I got previous mistake:Failure to find org.codeartisans.thirdparties.swing:org-openide-util:nbm:8.6.2 in https://repository.sonatype.org/service/local/repositories/atlassian/content was cached in the local repository. But I'm convinced  org-openide-util is existing there. Can you explain me whats wrong?

Comment: I tried to add <type>jar</type>. Unfortunately it demand "nbm" stubbornly.